# PCL Normal estimation with PointNormal

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The NormalEstimation nodelet in pcl_ros produces point clouds whose point type is Normal (i.e., not including xyz).  I have code that needs to work with PointNormals, i.e., x, y, z, nx, ny, nz.  Now I could just subscribe to both the normal cloud and the original cloud but then I have to worry about time synchronization as well.  Is there a simple way of solving this problem that doesn't require duplicating and modifying pcl_ros/normal_3d.cpp?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238049/pcl-normal-estimation-with-pointnormal/) by [bhaskarama](https://answers.ros.org/users/27283/bhaskarama/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-06-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

//Concatenate the XYZ and normal fields*

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>::Ptr cloud_with_normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>);
pcl::concatenateFields (*original_XYZ_cloud, *normals, *cloud_with_normals);
```

---

Originally posted by [buckley.toby](https://answers.ros.org/users/30452/buckley.toby/) with karma: 116 on 2017-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2